# How would I test this simple method using Junit?

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito

This is the code I want to test:

```
public class ValidateRegisterInputController {

    public boolean validateInputHandle(UserDataObject user1){
    ValidateInput validateinput = new ValidateInput();
    boolean check = true;

    if (!validateinput.validateUsername(user1.getUsername())) {
        check = false;
        BanUserGUI bangui = new BanUserGUI();
        bangui.displayBanGUI();
    }

    return check;
   }
```

When I try to run the test however, it launches the "bangui.displayBanGUI()" method and goes to the console requesting input, meaning the test never properly finishes running. This is my test so far:

```
public class ValidateRegisterInputControllerTest {

    @Test
    public void testValidateRegisterInputControllervalidateInputHandleReturnsStringvalidWhenValidInputIsMade(){
    UserDataObject user1 = new UserDataObject(" ", "password1", "John", "Smith", 1);
    ValidateRegisterInputController controller = new ValidateRegisterInputController();

    assertTrue(controller.validateInputHandle(user1));

    }

}
```

So basically, if I enter a valid username (For example, "John"), this test will pass because it not display the GUI and will simply return check, which is true.

However, if I enter an invalid username such "  " (which is just blank spaces), then it should return false, but it will not due to the GUI launching.

How can I stop it launching the GUI and just finishing the method off. I was thinking mockito might come in handy, but I've only learnt theory for it, and never actually implemented it!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you doing want to test the GUI, why bother testing this method? Without the GUI you're basically testing if Java works. Also, reversing the boolean testwould make the method read more cleanly, IMO, and I wouldn't use a temporary variable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. if I wanted to test that GUI's would run if I put in an invalid username, would there be a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should inject BanUserGUI construction into your code. Use javax.inject.Provider. Alternatively you should extract method:

```
public class ValidateRegisterInputController {

    public boolean validateInputHandle(UserDataObject user1){
    ValidateInput validateinput = new ValidateInput();
    boolean check = true;

    if (!validateinput.validateUsername(user1.getUsername())) {
        check = false;
        BanUserGUI bangui = createBanUserGui();
        bangui.displayBanGUI();
    }

    return check;
   }

   BanUserGUI createBanUserGui()
   {
     return new BanUserGUI();
   }
}
```

After it you could just simply override the method in the unit test to return mock instead or use spy to mock method call.